# Java: How to drawString() from ascender line

Tags: java, java-2d

I am displaying some graphics text on Screen by using the drawString(. . .) function of Java2D Library.

Refering to the figure in this [article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) i want my string to be drawn from Ascender Line rather than BaseLine. In simple words is there any way to calculate the height b/w ascender line and Base Line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the [`FontMetrics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) object of the used font, and determine the ascent using `getAscent()` or `getMaxAscent()`, whichever is appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 8):

A normal `drawString` will align the base-line with the `y`-argument. If you want to draw the string so that the ascent-line is align with `y`, you need to pass `y + fm.getAscent()` where `fm` is the current `FontMetrics` object. See example below.

This screen shot:

[image]

is produced by this code:

```
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 10);

g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawString("Hello frog", 10, 10 + fm.getAscent());
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `FontMetrics.getAscent()` to the y position before rendering.

Comment: Shouldn't he *add* that value to the *y* before drawing the string?